# Update UILabel inside UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, nstimer, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Here is my code for my collectionView:

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let cellWidth = self.view.frame.size.width / 3 - 15
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = cellWidth / 15

    // Fetch final image - if it exists
    if let finalImage = collectedRows[indexPath.row]["picture"] as? PFFile {
      finalImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
          if let imageData = imageData {

            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height))
            imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
            cell.addSubview(imageView)

            if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
                if !UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled() {
                  cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

                  let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
                  let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
                  //always fill the view
                  blurEffectView.frame = cell.bounds
                  blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]

                  cell.addSubview(blurEffectView)
            } else {
                  let overLayer = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height))
                  overLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                  overLayer.alpha = 0.75
                  cell.addSubview(overLayer)
                }
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
              let overLayer = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height))
              overLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
              overLayer.alpha = 0.75
              cell.addSubview(overLayer)
            }

            //Create time Left label

            if let sentDate = self.collectedRows[indexPath.row]["sentAt"] as? NSDate {
              print("sentDate: \(sentDate)")
              let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

              if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
                let expiryDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 1, toDate: sentDate, options: NSCalendarOptions())
                let currentDate = NSDate()
                let differenceTime = calendar.components([.Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: currentDate, toDate: expiryDate!, options: NSCalendarOptions())
                print("sendDate2: \(differenceTime)")
                let hoursLeft = String(differenceTime.hour)
                let minutesLeft = String(differenceTime.minute)
                let secondsLeft = String(differenceTime.second)

                if (Int(hoursLeft)! <= 0 && Int(minutesLeft)! <= 0 && Int(secondsLeft)! <= 0) {
                  //remove object from parse
                  self.collectedRows[indexPath.row].deleteInBackground()
                  self.collectedRows[indexPath.row].saveInBackground()
                } else {
                  let timerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height))
                  timerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-Semibold", size: 16)
                  timerLabel.textAlignment = .Center
                  timerLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                  timerLabel.text = "\(hoursLeft):\(minutesLeft):\(secondsLeft)"
                  cell.addSubview(timerLabel)
                  cell.bringSubviewToFront(timerLabel)
                }
              } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
                let timerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height))
                timerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-Semibold", size: 16)
                timerLabel.textAlignment = .Center
                timerLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                timerLabel.numberOfLines = 2
                timerLabel.text = "Less than \n24 Hours Left"
                cell.addSubview(timerLabel)
                cell.bringSubviewToFront(timerLabel)

              }
            }

            if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            let deleteButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width/2, cell.frame.size.height * 0.75, cell.frame.size.width/2, cell.frame.size.height/4))
            deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            deleteButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
            deleteButton.setTitle("...", forState: .Normal)
            deleteButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-Bold", size: 32)
            cell.addSubview(deleteButton)
            deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: "removeFromProfile:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            } else {
              // DO NOT even show button
            }
            cell.layer.cornerRadius = cell.frame.size.width / 15
            cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return cell
  }
```

I am creating a UICollectionViewCell that has a blurred photo and a UILabel on top that is a 24 hour countdown label. That all works fine. However, I want the UILabel to update every second so it is continuously counting down. I know that I can create an NSTimer to update the entire UICollectionView every second (using collection.reloadData()). That obviously causes memory issues and crashes the app. Does anyone know how to update just the label? Or does anyone know how to pull the label creation out of this method and then apply the label to the appropriate cell atIndexPath and then call the new method (label creation) using NSTimer.scheduledWithInterval? The section marked:

```
//Create time Left label
```

is the only section I need updated every second.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a weak property in your class to hold a reference to timerLabel and set the property in your cellForItemAtIndexPath function.

Your timer function should be able to use that property to update the label without reloading the collection view (as long as it's still part of the view hierarchy).

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom cell class (may be add a nib file as well to clean up that mess), add a timer property, and then you can start the timer from `cellForRowAtIndex`. Don't forget to invalidate the timer in `deinit` and `prepareForReuse`.

Comment: I have created the custom cell class. However, what does this timer do in cellForRowAtIndex? I mean, I know it needs to update the label but how?